# Probleme jquery and PHP with multiple submits in dialog

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui, submit, modal-dialog

I can't delete the good comment, it always delete the last one.

my js:

```
  $(function () {          
        $( ".delete" ).click(function() {
            $( "#delete-confirm" ).dialog( "open" );
        });

        $( "#delete-confirm" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false, modal: true, width: '600px', show: 'fade',
            buttons: {
                "Confimer": function() {

                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    $('.form-comment').append('<input type="hidden" name="delete" />');
                    $(".form-comment").submit();
                },
                "Annuler": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });

    });
```

And in PHP :

```
<?php
 foreach ($commentManager->getList() as $comment) { ?>
     <form class="form-comment" method="post" style="display: inline;">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $comment['id']; ?>" />
      </form>
<?php } ?>
```

How can i submit the form with the good id withtout put my jquery code in the middle of the php page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly that you want to delete only the selected comment. So you can try something like:

```
var goodId = '';
$( ".delete" ).click(function() {
    goodId = $(this).attr('id');
    $( "#delete-confirm" ).dialog( "open" );
});
// and then later make these changes
$('.form-comment-'+goodId).append('<input type="hidden" name="delete" />');
$(".form-comment-"+goodId).submit();
goodId = '';
```

and in your php code:

```
<?php
 foreach ($commentManager->getList() as $comment) { ?>
     <form class="form-comment-<?php echo $comment['id']; ?>" method="post" style="display: inline;">
        <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $comment['id']; ?>" name="id" value="<?php echo $comment['id']; ?>" />
     </form>
<?php } ?>
```

To set the goodId You can use the value attribute to get the comment id if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you made AJAX request on that it will be better just get the current clicked DOM

and assign `attr-table-id` to it then use `$(this).data('table-id');` and send it via AJAX to your server

If you don't want to use AJAX  , make a redirect rather than sink in form submit issues because you are submitting all forms with the class `form-comment` `(Use window.location)`

I hope this can help